# flask routing fails on multi get requests

Tags: python, flask

trying to get 2 get requests

1. allUsers
2. userById

```
 from http import HTTPStatus
from app import db
from flask_restful import Resource, marshal_with
import app.dal.models as models
from app.resources.authentication.authentication_utils import user_creation_parser
import app.resources.errors as errors


class User(Resource):
    MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 10

    @marshal_with(models.User.marshaller())
    def get(self, *args):
        if len(args)>0:
            user = models.User.query.get(args[0])
            if not user:
                raise errors.NoSuchUser
            return user, HTTPStatus.OK
        else:
            users = models.User.query.all()
            if not users:
                raise errors.NoUsersFound
            return users, HTTPStatus.OK
```

```
get 127.0.0.1:5000/user
```

result all users

```
get 127.0.0.1:5000/user/1
```

fails

when trying 2 separated function

```
    @marshal_with(models.User.marshaller())
    def get(self, user_id):
        user = models.User.query.get(user_id)
        if not user:
            raise errors.NoSuchUser
        return user, HTTPStatus.OK

    @marshal_with(models.User.marshaller())
    def get(self):
        users = models.User.query.all()
        if not users:
            raise errors
        return users, HTTPStatus.OK
```

have same result.

having only 1 function of each works fine.

Comment: You can not overload functions in Python. Give `user` a default value (for example `None`).

Comment: technically you can overload with `@singledispatch` but haven't tried it with flask. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch

Comment: @eagr That is a neat little trick using some reflection and registered functions. It simulates overloading, but it is not overloading. In the end the namespace of a class is a dictionary and there can be only one key `get` in it.